# Avoid Overflow from Exponential With Very large negative numbers python

Tags: python, overflow, exponent

I am writing a code where I calculate an exponential distribution from data points. When running the code, the exponential resulted in arrays of zero. To avoid overflow, I took the log of the exponential. After taking the log, these are the values I get:

```
LL = [-2.206e+007 -5.209e+037 -1.525e+023 -2.761e+075 -5.577e+015 -4.774e+021 -3.420e+030 -8.149e+035 -1.320e+023 -8.438e+065]
```

I then subtract the Maximum value from the array to further help avoid overflow. However, when I take the exponent again afterwards all of my values are zero except for the maximum value which is equal to 1.

I think it is because the values are so large that subtracting the maximum value doesn't make a difference. 
Is there a way to further avoid overflow in my calculations after taking the log and subtracting the maximum logged value before taking the exponent again?

Comment: Python has arbitrary precision arithmetic. You're not going to overflow, so long as you're using pure Python.

Comment: @jhpratt: Python has arbitrary-precision integers by default, but if you want to use an arbitrary-precision real number representation, you're going to have to do so manually.

Comment: Looking at this, the *logarithms* of your values go down to -2.761e+075. That is an absurdly high magnitude for a logarithm. I don't know what the context here is, but you may need to just accept that this is going to underflow.